# Literal Characters in Regex Character Classes

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

While looking through some regex stuff, I found that you could put Literal Characters inside of a character class.  I know when using character classes you can use ranges to shortcut instead of specifying every letter/number in a range, IE: `[1-47-9]` matches every number except 0,5,6.

If you have a regex including literal characters in a character class, does it treat this the same way and match the range of those characters?  For example, would `[\000-\005]` positively match `\000, \001, \002, \003, \004, \005`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does work this way.  You can specify a range between any arbitrary characters and as long as the code point of the left side is less than the code point of the right side the range will match any character between them (inclusive).

Comment: @f-j so `[\009-\000]` is invalid in the same sense `[9-0]` is invalid?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep, note that you can even make ranges with seemingly unrelated characters.  For example you could make a character class for all printable ASCII characters using `[ -~]`.